# AngularJS SmartTable persistent state not held with custom search (scope issue?)

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

Using AngularJS and SmartTable...
I have a Persistent State which works fine when filters are applied within the table.
I then added a custom search field which searches all columns.
This also works.
However the filter this applied is not held by my persistent state directive.
I believe its a scope issue but cannot seem to line the two up to meet.

Here is a Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/2qt7f6NxKH2blJ5GudNl?p=preview

Is my scope written incorrectly?

Here's my directive for the custom search

```
//  Text Search for all columns in stTable
//  USAGE: <input type="text" ng-model="queryAllColumns"/>
//  There HAS TO BE a way to implement this into the stPersist
.directive('searchWatchModel',function(){
  return {
    require:'^stTable',
    scope:{
      searchWatchModel:'='
    },
    link:function(scope, ele, attr, ctrl){
      var table=ctrl;

      scope.$watch('searchWatchModel',function(val){
        ctrl.search(val);
      });

    }
  };
})
```

And here is my Persistent Table directive

```
//  Create a Persistant Table Display
//  Allows you to close the browser and return with filters still applied
//  USAGE: on the st-able  ADD: st-persist="myTable"  <--myTable can be anything
.directive('stPersist', function () {
    return {
        require: '^stTable',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            var nameSpace = attr.stPersist;

            //save the table state every time it changes
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return ctrl.tableState();
            }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                    localStorage.setItem(nameSpace, JSON.stringify(newValue));
                }
            }, true);

            //fetch the table state when the directive is loaded
            if (localStorage.getItem(nameSpace)) {
                var savedState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(nameSpace));
                var tableState = ctrl.tableState();

                angular.extend(tableState, savedState);
                ctrl.pipe();

            }

        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is already a "global search" available with smart-table.

```
<input st-search placeholder="global search" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
```

so why do you have to create your own custom search ? maybe i'm missing something.

By the way, you should add a throttle / delay to your stPersist Directive to avoid unnecessary setItem on localStorage.

Comment: This is just a prototype "make sure the basic works first". Global doesn't search dates very well.  I'm relatively new to angular... any suggestions on a research for understanding throttle/delay on the stPersist? ... I'm not sure how I'd write that? And are you referring to type-ahead searching... as soon as I type "a..." it caches to local storage?  ... I did see a built in delay on st-search of 400ms... Is that what you're referring to?